# Converting JSON data to Python object while ignoring Lists

Tags: python, json

I have JSON file that contains the structure of neural networks. I would like to convert the JSON file to an object, but, if possible, ignore the lists.

For example, this is the content of the JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "model_6",
  "network": {
    "input_shape": [3],
    "output_shape": [9, 50],
    "layers": [
      {"type": "Linear", "in_features": 3, "out_features": 1024},
      {"type": "ReLU"},
      {"type": "View", "shape": [-1, 16, 64]},
      {"type": "Conv1d", "in_channels": 16, "out_channels": 32, "kernel_size": 3, "padding":0, "dilation":2},
      # ...
    ]
  }
}
```

And I would like to be able to access like an object, e.g. config.network.layers but having the list not converted into an object. Therefore, for example,

```
print(config.network.layers)
```

would give me :

```
[
  {"type": "Linear", "in_features": 3, "out_features": 1024},
  {"type": "ReLU"},
  {"type": "View", "shape": [-1, 16, 64]},
  {"type": "Conv1d", "in_channels": 16, "out_channels": 32, "kernel_size": 3, "padding":0, "dilation":2}
  # ...
]
```

I tried using the solution using SimpleNamespace:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

with open('model.json') as f:
    config = json.loads(f.read(), object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
```

But it is really not that convenient for my application because what is inside the list also get converted into object and it messes up with other parts of the code

Comment: i don't understand what you try to do but maybe you should read it normally and later convert some values to expected format.

Comment: I found that I can get back what is inside the list using __dict__ but I don't like this solution so much

Comment: if you don't want it as dict then you may have it only as `string` - and you can use `json.dumps()` to convert it to `string`

Comment: to get it as `config.network.layers` you would have to create manually object `config` with variable `network` which is a object with variable `layers`. I don't know if it wouldn't simpler to create object with original dictionary and function `__get__`  which will convert `config.network` to `config['network']` and `config.network.layers` to `config["network"]["layers"]`.

Comment: or maybe you should create more complex function for `object_hook` and use `if/else` with `isinstance(..., list)` to skip `SimpleNamespace` for lists.

Comment: please point to the list you want to ignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the issue is to convert a nested dict into dot-accessible nested objects.

You can use the famous `Bunch` pattern to turn a dict into a dot-accessible object:

```
class Bunch(object):
    def __init__(self, adict):
        self.__dict__.update(adict)
```

And then use it recursively for the nested dicts:

```
def to_bunch(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return Bunch({k: to_bunch(v) for k, v in d.items()})
    return d
```

**Usage example**:

```
d = json.loads("""
{
  "name": "model_6",
  "network": {
    "input_shape": [3],
    "output_shape": [9, 50],
    "layers": [
      {"type": "Linear", "in_features": 3, "out_features": 1024},
      {"type": "ReLU"},
      {"type": "View", "shape": [-1, 16, 64]},
      {"type": "Conv1d", "in_channels": 16, "out_channels": 32, "kernel_size": 3, "padding":0, "dilation":2}
    ]
  }
}
""")
```

Then:

```
>>> config = to_bunch(d)
... config.network.layers
[{'type': 'Linear', 'in_features': 3, 'out_features': 1024},
 {'type': 'ReLU'},
 {'type': 'View', 'shape': [-1, 16, 64]},
 {'type': 'Conv1d',
  'in_channels': 16,
  'out_channels': 32,
  'kernel_size': 3,
  'padding': 0,
  'dilation': 2}]
```

Bonus: in an interactive environment, you get tab-completion! (E.g. start with `config.` and hit `<TAB>`, and it will show you `name` and `network`, etc.)

Comment: It is perfect :) Thank you so much !